# How to access DVA Store in UMI application?

Tags: redux, umijs, dvajs

Hi most of the react developers would find dvaJS and umiJS, heaven for state management and application development. Dva is `elm` based state management tool that use `react-redux` for state management.

Q: How to access DVA Store in UMI application, outside the component or without `connect`?

Q: How to `dispatch` DVA Store in UMI application, outside the component or without `connect`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: How to access DVA Store in UMI application, outside the component or without `connect`?

A: https://v2.umijs.org/guide/with-dva.html#how-to-access-store-or-dispatch

It says use:

```
window.g_app._store
```

Q: How to `dispatch` DVA Store in UMI application, outside the component or without `connect`?

A: https://v2.umijs.org/guide/with-dva.html#how-to-access-store-or-dispatch

It says use:

```
window.g_app._store.dispatch('namespace/action')
```

## Bonus:

Q: How to `get state of` DVA Store in UMI application, outside the component or without `connect`?

A: https://v2.umijs.org/guide/with-dva.html#how-to-access-store-or-dispatch

It says use:

```
window.g_app._store.getState()
```

Available Functions:

```
asyncReducers: {}
dispatch: ƒ ()
getState: ƒ f()
replaceReducer: ƒ (n)
runSaga: ƒ ()
subscribe: ƒ subscribe(listener)
```

Recommended: Instead of directly using it, write a Util that exports these functions.

Answer (score 1):

To access or dispatch DVA store in UMI app, you can use DVA hooks in functional components without connect. It can be only used with DVA v2.6.x.

In a functional component:

- Access store:

```
const state = useSelector(state => state)
// If state in DVA store changed, rendered values in "state" can be changed in page too.
```

or

```
const store = useStore()
const state = store.getState()
// If state in DVA store changed, rendered values in "state" won't be changed in page.
```

- Dispatch:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
dispatch({type: "namespace/action", payload: 12345})
```

Answer (score 1):

As and extra reference and for those searching for accessing the `dva` app reference outside of a `react` component context while using:

- *Umi.js v3+*
- Along with *dva 2.6+* (as per the framework compatibility)

You can use the `getDvaApp` exported method:

```js
import { getDvaApp } from 'umi';

const dispatch = getDvaApp()._store.dispatch;

// use the `dispatch`
```